# How to make postman assertion on an array

Tags: postman, postman-newman

```
"thing": [
            {
                "id": 1,
            }
         ]
```

How do I assert that thing is an array with an object that contains ID

I tried

`expect(response.thing).to.deep.include('id');`

But that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check:

- the array contains String `id`

`pm.expect(JSON.stringify(response.thing)).to.deep.include('id');`

- a nested object has key `id`

`pm.expect(response.thing[0]).to.have.keys('id');`